# Create a whole bunch of new objects

Tags: ruby, class, object

Very new to programming. I'm trying to create a bunch of new objects in ruby with a new class that I defined. So for example here is my class:

```
class Loser

  def initialize (fingers)
    @fingers = fingers
  end

  def fingerprint
    return @fingers
  end
end
```

So lets say I want to make 10 losers. The first loser has 1 finger, the second loser has 2 fingers... etc.

Rather than going through

```
loser1 = Loser.new(1)
loser2 = Loser.new(2)
etc,
```

I thought I could do something like

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
array.each {|i| loser#{i} = Loser.new(i)}
```

I want

```
puts Loser5.fingerprint
```

to output 5 which totally doesn't work. Any suggestions please. This may be very simple. I am new.

Comment: Store your "losers" in an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
losers = [];
1.upto(10) do |i|
  losers << Loser.new(i)
end
```

Edit (credit to @meager) if you want to make it a little shorter:

```
losers = 1.upto(10).map {|i| Loser.new(i)}
```

Comment: This patten should basically never be used when `map` is available: `losers = 1.upto(10).map { |i| Loser.new(i) }`.

Comment: @meagar: I forgot you could use map on enumerators. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
class Loser
  def initialize (fingers)
    @fingers = fingers
  end

  def fingerprint
    return @fingers
  end
end

losers = (1..10).map { |n| Loser.new(n) }
losers[4].fingerprint # => 5
```

Answer (score 1):

How is this ?

```
class Loser
  def initialize (fingers)
    @fingers = fingers
  end

  def fingerprint
    return @fingers
  end
end

losers = 1.upto(10).map(&Loser.method(:new))
p losers[4].fingerprint # => 5
```

Comment: Nice, rubyish, and elegant. A little harder for someone new to Ruby to understand, but +1 anyway.

Comment: Why would you use the significantly more cryptic `(&Loser.method(:new))` instead of `{ |i| Lower.new(i) }`?

Comment: @meagar: it looks clever and does not repeat your comment. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is very basic, and you could do a lot of things to make this more complex, but I'll give you a simple example.  You can set up a constant as an array that keeps track of instances of the class Loser.  For example:

```
class Loser 

LOSERS = []

  def initialize(fingers)
    @fingers = fingers
    LOSERS << self
  end

  def fingerprint
    LOSERS.count
  end
end
```

However, this is entirely dependent upon the number of instances that are in the LOSERS array.